# Space in URL path ("/path/subpath name") leads to "Invalid HTTP Version: &#x27;name" error

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have the following nginx configuration:

```
  location ~* ^/path/(.*) {
    set $query $1;
    proxy_pass http://backend_app/$query;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
```

I expect nginx to proxy the request from `http://frontend/path/subpath name` to `http://backend_app/subpath name`. But I am seeing some weird behavior:

`http://frontend/path/subpath` --> `http://backend_app/path/subpath` works fine.

BUT

`http://frontend/path/subpath name` --> returns a 400 bad request with the following error message:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Server: nginx/1.16.1
< Date: Sat, 06 Feb 2021 01:13:15 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 198
< Connection: keep-alive
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
<
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bad Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>Bad Request</p></h1>
    Invalid HTTP Version &#x27;Invalid HTTP Version: &#x27;name HTTP/1.0&#x27;&#x27;
  </body>
</html>
* Connection #0 to host frontend left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Notice the error message in the response says `Invalid HTTP Version &#x27;Invalid HTTP Version: &#x27;name HTTP/1.0&#x27;&#x27;`

So nginx is interpreting the word after the space in the path as part of the http version name.

I tried this with URL encoding as well but still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Just learned about URI normalization and I was able to fix this problem by following this config:

```
  location /path {
    rewrite /path/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass http://backend_app;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
```

And things are working as expected.